# Oracle ODT for VS2017 and VS2019

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2017 with ODT installed and Visual Studio 2019 installed. I'm about to attempt to install ODT for VS2019 and I see on Oracle's site it says to uninstall any ODT. However, the download for ODT seems to be specific for VS2017 and VS2019.

Do I need to uninstall ODT for VS2017 and then installed ODT for VS2019 or just install ODT for VS2019 and not remove the ODT for VS2017? If I have to uninstall ODT for VS2017 will the install of ODT for VS2019 work on both VS2017 and VS2019?

Comment: Which driver or tool do you like to use?

Comment: Usually Entity Framework within Visual Studio.

Comment: If you don't need the connection wizard or database browser then you can just install the Oracle client, the ODT tools are not needed

Answer (score 0):

I didn't remove ODT for VS2017 and just installed ODT for VS2019. Seemed to install without any problems which is unusual for me and Oracle products. I was able to open up VS2019 and use the Server Explorer to connect to the database. Now I'm going to look into getting Entity Framework to work with VS2019.